# Invalid grant при получении access_token vk api на django

Tags: python, django, vkontakte-api

Я пытаюсь получить access_token, используя для этого code, чтобы авторизовать пользователя на своём сайте через ВК. Получение code происходит успешно, но когда я использую этот code для получения access_token я всё время получаю ошибку "Code is invalid or expired". В приложении в ВК
http://127.0.0.1:1970/vk_thru_auth добавлено в доверенные redirect_uri.
url:

```py
path('vk_auth', views.VKAuth.as_view(), name='vk-login'), 
path('vk_thru_auth', views.VK_through_auth)
```

views:

```py
class VKAuth(DataMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main_menu/vk_auth.html'
    auth_response = requests.get('https://oauth.vk.com/authorize',
                                 params={
                                     'client_id' : client_id,
                                     'redirect_uri' : 'http://127.0.0.1:1970/vk_thru_auth',
                                     'display' : 'page',
                                     'scope'  : 'offline',
                                     'response_type' : 'code',
                                 })

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        add_context = super().get_user_context(**kwargs)
        context['auth_link'] = self.auth_response.url
        return context | add_context

def VK_through_auth(request):
    if request.GET.get('code', None):
        auth_response = requests.get('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token',
                                     params={
                                         'client_id': client_id,
                                         'client_secret': app_key,
                                         'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:1970/vk_thru_auth',
                                         'code': request.GET.get('code', None),
                                         'v': '5.131'
                                     })
        return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_response.url)
    if request.GET.get('token', None):
        pass
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказано в [документации](https://dev.vk.com/api/access-token/authcode-flow-community#%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) VK API:

> #### Открытие диалога авторизации
>
> Необходимо перенаправить браузер пользователя по адресу
> https://oauth.vk.com/authorize, передав следующие параметры:
> ...

Поэтому не сервер должен отправлять запрос, а пользователь открыть страницу в браузере (в вашем случае, например через Redirect). На этой странице пользователь разрешает приложению получить доступ к аккаунту.

[image: Пример диалога авторизации]